# How are batteries cooled in passenger aircraft?

Tags: electrical-system, battery

What sort of systems are used to cool batteries in the air? Liquid cooled? Air cooled?

I am interested in lithium chemistry batteries in the form of either pouch cells or 18650 batteries inside of boxes placed in the fuselage or wing.

Comment: What type of batteries are you interested in?

Comment: Lithium chemistry batteries such as Li-Ion or Li-Po

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, current aviation lithium batteries do not use active cooling.

I know the True Blue Power [TB17](https://www.truebluepowerusa.com/tb17/) (Robinson R44 & R66, Bell 505 Jet Ranger X) and [TB44](https://www.truebluepowerusa.com/tb44/) (Cessna Caravan, DHC-6, DHC-8) do not require active cooling.

I haven't seen any easily accessible info on the Saft batteries for the A350.

Answer (score 2):

From [this presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/FernandoNobre1/a319-320-321-flight-deck-and-systems-briefing-for-pilots) for the A320 family:

> **Battery ventilation**
>
> Achieved by ambient air being drawn around the batteries and then vented directly outboard via a venturi.

So the ventilation air provides cooling as well, especially when at cruise altitude. Batteries in the avionics bay are further cooled by a separate aircon system. From the same presentation:

[image]

Comment: Does the A320 family uses Li batteries?

Comment: @mins From what I've found, the A320 family uses NiCd batteries.

Comment: @selectstriker2: I got that info too, so the post doesn't answer the question which is about "*lithium chemistry batteries*".

Comment: @mins I can remove it if required.

Comment: "Ventilation" makes it sound like the primary purpose is preventing buildup of corrosive and/or flammable gaseous chemicals, not cooling?

Comment: @rackandboneman Could be. The fan blow in cold air though.